# Using AWS Blue/Green deployment, how do I modify the staging database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-replication

AWS has rolled out a Blue/Green Deployment feature for RDS, allow you to create a staging (green) database that's in parallel with your production (blue) database. Their documentation specifically says you can make changes and test them out, however:

- It's readonly by default
- It's got replication, syncing the green to the blue
- I can't create a SUPER user to disable readonly mode or disable replication.

I understand why they'd default to those, changes could mess up replication, and without replication you'd lose data unless you manually copy data over in a way that's compatible with whatever changes you make to the green. I'm willing to manage that, but can't actually figure out how to modify the database! With no SUPER user I can't run:

```
STOP REPLICA;
set GLOBAL read_only = false;
```

And apparently AWS RDS doesn't allow SUPER users, and there's no way in the console to disable either of these.

What am I missing? Does green/blue only allow you to upgrade MySQL versions? Seems like a big limitation, not really spelled out anywhere.

Comment: I am wondering the same exact thing. Their documentation clearly states that making schema modifications to the green staging instance should be doable. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the Green Deployment primary endpoint is read-only by default.

If your use case requires you to make write operations or schema changes you will need to apply a new DB parameter group to the primary instance with `read_only` parameter set to `0`.

*(The `read_only` parameter is a dynamic parameter, and therefore no reboot is required when applied.)*

Here are some general steps to apply the new parameter group:

1. Create a new Parameter Group or clone your existing Parameter Group.
2. Once the Parameter group is created, modify the parameter `read_only` and set the value from the default `{TrueIfReplica}` to `0`.
3. Select the Green Deployment primary instance and modify the DB parameter group to the new group from the drop-down via the Additional Configuration section.
4. Once the DB parameter group is updated, select "Apply immediately" in the schedule modification and click on Modify DB Instance.

Verification:

```
MySQL [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE menagerie;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.148 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> show variables where variable_name='innodb_read_only';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| innodb_read_only | OFF   |
+------------------+-------+
```